# Macro overloading

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to define something like this:

```
#define FOO(x, y) BAR()
#define FOO(x, sth, y) BAR(sth)
```

so that this:

```
FOO("daf", sfdas);
FOO("fdsfs", something, 5);
```

is translated to this:

```
BAR();
BAR(something);
```

?

Edit:
Actually, `BAR`'s are methods of my class. Sorry for not saying that before (didn't think it was relevant).

Answering DyP's question:

```
class Testy
{
    public:
    void TestFunction(std::string one, std::string two, std::string three)
    {
        std::cout << one << two << three;
    }
    void AnotherOne(std::string one)
    {
        std::cout << one;
    }
    void AnotherOne(void)
    {
        std::cout << "";
    }
};

#define PP_NARG(...) PP_NARG_(__VA_ARGS__,PP_RSEQ_N())
#define PP_NARG_(...) PP_ARG_N(__VA_ARGS__)
#define PP_ARG_N(_1, _2, _3, N, ...) N
#define PP_RSEQ_N() 3, 2, 1, 0

// macro for exactly 2 arguments
#define FOO_2(_1, _2) AnotherOne()
// macro for exactly 3 arguments
#define FOO_3(_1, _2, _3) AnotherOne(_2)

// macro selection by number of arguments
#define FOO_(N) FOO_##N
#define FOO_EVAL(N) FOO_(N)
#define TestFunction(...) FOO_EVAL(PP_NARG(__VA_ARGS__))(__VA_ARGS__)
```

And call:

```
Testy testy;
testy.TestFunction("one", "two", "three");   // line 9
```

Compiler output:

> Warning   1   warning C4003: not enough actual parameters for macro 'PP_ARG_N'    main.cpp    9
>
> Warning   2   warning C4003: not enough actual parameters for macro 'FOO_'    main.cpp    9
>
> Error 3   error C2039: 'FOO_' : is not a member of 'Testy'    main.cpp    9

Comment: It's possible to let it expand to `BAR(sfdas);` and `BAR(something, 5);` respectively. Is this acceptable? Macros can't "discard" the last parameter, but they can discard the first.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850421/can-i-define-variadic-c-preprocessor-macros-with-va-args-in-the-middle-instead

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Edit ------------------------------------------------look here----------------------------------------------------------------->

([Overloading macro on number of arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761703/overloading-macro-on-number-of-arguments))

```
// functions, or macros, ....
void bar(){}
void bar(int){}

#define EXPAND(X) X    // for MSVC10 compatibility

// compute number of (variadic) macro arguments
// from http://groups.google.com/group/comp.std.c/browse_thread/thread/77ee8c8f92e4a3fb/346fc464319b1ee5?pli=1
#define PP_NARG(...) EXPAND( PP_NARG_(__VA_ARGS__, PP_RSEQ_N()) )
#define PP_NARG_(...) EXPAND( PP_ARG_N(__VA_ARGS__) )
#define PP_ARG_N(_1, _2, _3, N, ...) N
#define PP_RSEQ_N() 3, 2, 1, 0


// macro for exactly 2 arguments
#define FOO_2(_1, _2) bar()
// macro for exactly 3 arguments
#define FOO_3(_1, _2, _3) bar(_2)

// macro selection by number of arguments
#define FOO_(N) FOO_##N
#define FOO_EVAL(N) FOO_(N)
#define FOO(...) EXPAND( FOO_EVAL(EXPAND( PP_NARG(__VA_ARGS__) ))(__VA_ARGS__) )

int main()
{
    int something = 42;
    FOO("daf", sfdas);
    FOO("fdsfs", something, 5);
}
```

Preprocessor output:

```
void bar(){}
void bar(int){}

int main()
{
    int something = 42;
    bar();
    bar(something);
}
```

---

Edit2: Seems like VS2010 has some issues with `__VA_ARGS__` and macro replacement.

UPDATE: It's ... a bug?? (also see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134523/msvc-doesnt-expand-va-args-correctly)):

```
#define MACRO2(PARAM0, PARAM1, ...) arg 0: >PARAM0<    arg 1: >PARAM1<    \
  additional args: >__VA_ARGS__<
#define MACRO1(...) MACRO2(__VA_ARGS__, OTHERARG_0, OTHERARG_1)

MACRO1(ARG0, ARG1);
```

Preprocessor output:

```
arg 0: >ARG0, ARG1<    arg 1: >OTHERARG_0<    additional args: >OTHERARG_1<;
```

For a workaround, see the linked SO question. I've updated the original answer (code) above and tested it with MSVC10 -> works now.

Comment: I've edited my question - `BAR` is a method of a class and your solution doesn't work for that (compiler says something about 'FOO_PP_NARG' not being a member of 'MyClass').

Comment: Compiler VS2010, the rest I provided in my question.

Comment: @NPS See my update. I'll try to find out what's the reason, though I guess it's a bug / non-standard behaviour in the VS2010 preprocessor.

Comment: This one works, thanks, but it still shows a warning: `warning C4003: not enough actual parameters for macro 'FOO_2'` (or `FOO_3`).

Comment: @NPS Please take a look at my (new) update. The old macro was buggy AFAIK.